# How get Node.JS fields value (submitted form data)

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, npm, node-modules

I use Node.js without framework (without-express).

My current code.

```
const { headers, method, url } = req;
  let body = [];
  req.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  }).on('data', (chunk) => {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', () => {
     console.log(body)
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

    console.log(body)
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html\; charset=utf-8'});
    res.write(body)
    res.end()
  });
```

The response

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAExpj6oapW6tzLe8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field-one"

Test value of field one
------WebKitFormBoundaryAExpj6oapW6tzLe8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field-two"

Test value of field-two
------WebKitFormBoundaryAExpj6oapW6tzLe8--
```

in this test example, the value of field-one is `Test value of field one` and field-two is `Test value of field two` How to get the value of this  fields by field name?

NPM module are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NPM module are acceptable

You can use [parse-formdata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-formdata) package.

```
const parseFormdata = require('parse-formdata')
const http = require('http')

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    parseFormdata(req, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            // Set whatever status code you want
            return res.end('Error...');
        }
        console.log('fields:', data.fields)
        data.parts.forEach(function(part) {
            console.log('part:', part.fieldname)
        });

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html\; charset=utf-8'
        });

        res.end();
    });

}).listen(8080)
```

You can read the code of that package if you want to learn to parse form-data yourself.

Comment: Thanks Mr Marcos. It's easy with this package. Is it also can be working with files data as field?

Comment: You're welcome!, Yeah `parts` is an array of streams for the multipart file uploads